# Ubuntu 6.2 and MariaDB ODBC Error Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so' : file not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb, odbc, unixodbc

Receiving the below error message when trying to connect to MariaDB using ODBC connection on Ubuntu 6.2 OS.  I've tried just about everything but it's not working

Error:

```
Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so' : file not found
```

Operating System:

```
Linux ubuntu 6.2.0-1013-raspi #15-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep  8 18:53:11 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

File Permissions:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/lib64# ls -l
total 2316
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2365512 Sep 24 19:07 libmaodbc.so
```

Information on Libmaodbc.so file:

```
readelf -l /usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x172d0
There are 7 program headers, starting at offset 64
```

ODBC Setup:

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.11
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[MariaDB]
Description=MariaDB
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
UsageCount=4
```

Testing:

```
isql -v -k "DRIVER={MariaDB};127.0.0.1;UID=admin;PWD=password"
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
```

Comment: check the rights of the file

Comment: @nbk The file permissions have 777 on the /usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so file

Comment: Perhaps need to run a `sudo ldconfig` to update the linker's cache?

Comment: I tried running the sudo ldconfig but still received the same error

root@ubuntu:/usr/lib64# sudo ldconfig
root@ubuntu:/usr/lib64# isql -v -k "DRIVER={MariaDB};127.0.0.1;UID=admin;PWD=password"
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
root@ubuntu:/usr/lib64#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by installing the correct architecture of the ODBC driver onto the system.  I'm running ubuntu on a aarch64 system, so I installed the aarch version of the ODBC drivers and not use the 64bit version.

Answer (score 0):

If libmaodbc.so is present, but the driver manager complains about file not found (dlopen returns NULL, errno=ENOENT) it means, that one or more dependencies of libmaodbc.so could not be loaded, e.g. libssl or libmariadb (Connector/C).

To check what is missing try

```
ldd libmaodbc.so
```

Other options are

- run isql with strace
- debugging: export LD_DEBUG=libs; isql -v -k .....

Comment: The LLD command returns the following response "ldd libmaodbc.so  not a dynamic executable"

Comment: Then it is obvious, that you installed wong architecture.